# Does the shape of a wire affect the electric current in it in any way?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, charge, conductors

Say we have a straight wire connected across two terminals carrying electricity between them. If everything is kept the same (voltage across the two terminals, resistance of the wire, etc.) will there be ANY difference at all if the wire were to be, let's say, tightly wound into a spiral as opposed to being straight?

I'm imagining there should be at least some difference because the spiral would make the electrons "bump" more along the edges. Is there any logic at all to this reasoning, or am I hopelessly illiterate about electricity?

Comment: What you are describing is called transmission line effects.

Comment: I think OP meant whether there is any difference in the case of a DC current. It is pretty obvious that there must be a difference in the case of AC current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, there is a difference.**

If you made the wire as you mentioned, into a spiral, like this:

[image]

then there is quite a big difference between this and a straight wire. The difference between a straight wire and a coil or spiral wire is that the spiral wire resists changes in current flow.

This is called an [inductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor) or [solenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid).

---

It resists changes in the current flow because when there is a changing current in the coil of wire, there is a [back EMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-electromotive_force) that counters the [EMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force) of the current entering the coil of wire. This makes it hard for current to pass (at least initially) through the coil of wire.

Inductors are characterized by the following equation:

$$v = L \frac{dI}{dt}$$

Where $v$ is the voltage, $L$ is the [inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#:%7E:text=In%20electromagnetism%20and%20electronics%2C%20inductance,magnetic%20field%20around%20the%20conductor.) and $\frac{dI}{dt}$ is the change in current with respect to time or how does current change when time ticks.

---

When the current is unchanging, the inductor behaves just like a normal wire. But when the current is changing, it behaves differently: the greater the change of the current, the greater the effect of the back EMF will be. At very high frequencies, the current will be mostly blocked, and theoretically, as the frequency approaches infinity, the resistance or impedance of the inductor will be infinite, and no current will pass.

Although straight wires also have inductance, it can be usually ignored because it is so small. Only in certain situations such as power line transmission, it becomes important to know the inductance of the straight wire where it cannot be ignored from the math when designing the power lines.

Comment: What causes this resistance? And why would an unchanging current face no resistance?

Comment: @a3y3 It is not resistance per se, it is the impedance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance), a more general term for resistance. Impedance from inductors comes from the fact that they cannot tolerate changes in the current very much (because magnetic fields do not like to change and inductors create a magnetic field), due to an effect called hysteresis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis). This magnetic field around the inductor resists changes in the current (it pushes back) and therefore it has impedance.

Comment: @a3y3 Now, why does an "unchanging current face no resistance"? Good question. The answer is that inductors like it when the current is constant and unchanging. This is because the magnetic field does not change when the current is unchanging. Therefore, the magnetic field is happy and does not push back on the current coming into the inductor. There is no hysteresis, and the magnetic field does not induce a back EMF (does not push back) on the current. All this makes the inductor behave just like a normal straight wire.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. So the answer to my question is "if it's an unchanging current (DC?), there's ABSOLUTELY no difference at all, due to the shape of the wire, but if it's a changing current (AC?) then there's a HUGE difference?

Comment: @a3y3 Essentially, yes. But there is a caveat here. When the current for DC first starts flowing, there is a change in current in the inductor (from no current to current). This means for a few milliseconds, the inductor resists the current and then stops resisting.